# javascript logic returning strange results

Tags: javascript, math, logic

I have a grid that I am trying to program a cursor onto, there is a central point in the grid and I am trying to make the cursor only be able to move x amount of squares from that central point, here is the code I have

```
var makecursor = function (axis, operation) {
    oppositeAxis = axis === 'y' ? 'x' : 'y';

    // app.cursor contains the x and y coordinates of the cursor
    app.cursor[axis] = 

    // calcualte the difference between the current cursor location and the origin
    Math.abs( app.cursor[axis] - origin[axis] ) + 

   // calculate the difference between the opposite axis and
   // the origin and add it to the previous calculation
    Math.abs( app.cursor[oppositAxis] - origin[oppositeAxis] ) 

  // add the operation to be performed ( movement of cursor, 1 or -1 )
  + operation 

  // if the sum of the x, y and current operation are greater then the allowed
  // movement, then make "app.cursor[axis]" equal to itself (dont move) , 
  // otherwise make "app.cursor[axis]" equal to itself plus the operation ( move )

> origin.movement ? app.cursor[axis] : app.cursor[axis] + operation;
}
```

"operation" is either 1 or -1, for directional

"origin.movement" is the number of squares from the origin you can move the cursor.

my hopes / expected behavior is that from a square on my grid, you can only move as many squares are specified in "origin.movement" variable. but it is returning strange numbers when i print out the results, and it doesn't calculate the locations correctly, i.e. origin should be zero, but is instead one, or two, depending on previous movements, many other anomalies that I haven't been able to understand. any help with this problem would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: sry its a bit late and im tired.. I didn't copy it right, fixed now.. i think, everything between `app.cursor[axis] =` and the end is on one line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I wasn't accounting for the operation correctly, I needed to add the operation to the axis I was moving on, so the statement

```
    Math.abs( app.cursor[axis] - origin[axis] ) + 

    // calculate the difference between the opposite axis and
    // the origin and add it to the previous calculation

    Math.abs( app.cursor[oppositeAxis] - origin[oppositeAxis] ) +

    // add the operation to be performed ( movement of cursor, 1 or -1 )
    operation;
```

should actually be like this:

```
// add operation to curser location to account for movement
Math.abs(( app.curser[axis] + operation ) - origin[axis] ) + 

// instead of the adding operation at the end
Math.abs( (app.curser[oppositeAxis]) - origin[oppositeAxis] );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put parens around the expression you're testing for `> origin.movement` in order to use that expression's result there; without them, the expression is broken up earlier:

```
var makecursor = function (axis, operation) {
    var oppositeAxis = axis === 'y' ? 'x' : 'y';

    app.cursor[axis] = (
        // calculate the difference between the current cursor location and the origin
        Math.abs( app.cursor[axis] - origin[axis] ) + 

        // calculate the difference between the opposite axis and
        // the origin and add it to the previous calculation
        Math.abs( app.cursor[oppositeAxis] - origin[oppositeAxis] ) +

        // add the operation to be performed ( movement of cursor, 1 or -1 )
        operation

        // if the sum of the x, y and current operation are greater then the allowed
        // movement, then make "app.cursor[axis]" equal to itself (dont move) , 
        // otherwise make "app.cursor[axis]" equal to itself plus the operation ( move )
    ) > operation ? app.cursor[axis] : app.cursor[axis] + operation;
}
```

**But**, I wouldn't do it on one long line with an assignment-to-self anyway, I'd break it up for clarity and ease of debugging, and just use an `if`:

So:

```
var makecursor = function (axis, operation) {
    var oppositeAxis = axis === 'y' ? 'x' : 'y';

    var movement = 
        // calculate the difference between the current cursor location and the origin
        Math.abs( app.cursor[axis] - origin[axis] ) + 

        // calculate the difference between the opposite axis and
        // the origin and add it to the previous calculation
        Math.abs( app.cursor[oppositeAxis] - origin[oppositeAxis] ) +

        // add the operation to be performed ( movement of cursor, 1 or -1 )
        operation;

    // If the sum of the x, y and current operation are less than or equal
    // to the allowed movement, add the operation to `app.cursor[axis]`
    if (movement <= origin.movement) {
        app.cursor[axis] += operation;
    }
}
```

---

Side note: Your code was also falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) by not declaring your `oppositeAxis` variable (there was also a typo using it later). I've fixed the typo and fixed the implicit global by adding `var` above.

Comment: still suffers from the same erroneous results.. i don't understand.. whats wrong with the logic?

Comment: I think there must be something weird going on with the variable input.. idk, thank you for your help!